# Stream realtime data to web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, lighttpd

I'm working on a project where we want to monitor data on a comm channel and provide feedback to a webpage. The data will be read by a process running on the webserver and then made available through IPC. The question is what is the best method of capturing this data and streaming it to the client through a webpage? We will probably be using lighttpd as our webserver.

Comment: look at socket.io for a compatibility layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use a technique called "Comet."

From the front-end you will need to utilize HTML5 web sockets, long-polling, or the hidden iframe technique to provide a live-enabled interface (or a combination of all 3 depending on the browser engine detected)

From the server-side (if you are using lighttpd), I would suggest using a message queue system like beanstalkd.  Combining beanstalkd, lighttpd, and php, you can create "infinitely loading" page that will sit and wait ("block") for new messages as they arrive in the beanstalkd queue (called a tube).  Once a new message is received, it can be outputted to the browser front end